# how to move a function in an other file

Tags: python

This is `myfunction.py`

```
def a():
  print 'function a'
  b()

def c():
  print 'function c'

from otherfunction import b

a()
```

And this is `otherfunction.py`

```
def b():
  print 'function b'
  c()
```

The expected output is

```
function a
function b
function c
```

Instead I get

```
function a
function b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/myfunction.py", line 10, in <module>
    a()
  File "/path/myfunction.py", line 3, in a
    b()
  File "/path/otherfunction.py", line 3, in b
    c()
NameError: global name 'c' is not defined
```

Well this is just a snippet but my actual function is pretty long and I'd like to move it in a different file, just a single function, not all the rest since that would mean to reformat a lot of code.

So, what's the correct way to do it?

### EDIT

If I change otherfunction.py to

```
from myfunction import c
def b():
    print 'function b'
    c()
```

I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/myfunction.py", line 8, in <module>
    from otherfunction import b
  File "/path/otherfunction.py", line 1, in <module>
    from myfunction import c
  File "/path/myfunction.py", line 8, in <module>
    from otherfunction import b
ImportError: cannot import name b
```

### EDIT 2

I changed otherfunction.py to

```
def b():
    from myfunction import c
    print 'function b'
    c()
```

Ant this is the output

```
function a
function a
function b
function c
function b
function c
```

It runs without errors, but apparently the functions are called multiple times? I don't really think I understand why this is happening. Even without errors, it's not what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You don't import c() in otherfunction, so it does not know it. Try:

```
from myfunction import c

def b():
  print 'function b'
  c()
```

but generally, it is a poor idea to create such circular references, it would be better to move c() function to yet another file

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
from myfunction import c
```

in `otherfunction.py`.

This will ensure that the code in `otherfunction.py` can see the `c` function, much like how you did `from otherfunction import b` in `myfunction.py`.

Also, Python will deal with the cyclic dependency so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: tried already, it doesn't work: i get `ImportError: cannot import name b`

Comment: `cannot import name b` implies you are doing `from myfunction import b` instead of `from myfunction import c`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'otherfunction.py' like this:

```
def b():
    from myfunction import c
    print 'function b'
    c()
```

Comment: i edited my post, it runs with no errors but doesn't produce the expected output